# SQL SERVER, ID column update to unique value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good morning, i have a big problem with an SQL server that hasn't been setted in the properly way, that server has some table with relations.
i have a TableA where there are 2 columns, ID and NUMBER_ORDER.
i have a TableB where there are 10 columns, the first one is a column of ID's related to the TableA, and other columns are related to the TEST of each NUMBER_ORDER.
Example:
TABLEA

| ID | NUMBER_ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 110000 |
| 2 | 110001 |
| 3 | 110002 |
| 4 | 110003 |

TABLEB

| ID | Test | date | NumberofTest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is a test for 110000 | 20/09/2022 10:15 | 1 |
| 1 | this is another test for 110000 | 20/09/2022 10:20 | 2 |
| 2 | this is a test for 110001 | 21/09/2022 9:10 | 1 |
| 2 | this is another test for 110001 | 21/09/2022 9:20 | 2 |

As u can see in TableB each ID of TableA appear more times because there are different Tests, this has suppose to be like this.

Now I explain my problem:

In this tables no PrimaryKey index has been setted.
what just happened as u can imagine is that now TableA have double ID's for different NUMBER_ORDER
in Table_B didn't changed a lot, cause records are writed correctly, but for example if ID "1" is doubled we have it doubled as well in TableB, like this,
Example DOUBLEID:
TABLEA

| ID | NUMBER_ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 110000 |
| 1 | 110001 |
| 2 | 110002 |
| 3 | 110003 |

TABLEB

| ID | Test | date | NumberofTest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is a test for 110000 | 20/09/2022 10:15 | 1 |
| 1 | this is another test for 110000 | 20/09/2022 10:20 | 2 |
| 1 | this is a test for 110001 | 21/09/2022 9:10 | 1 |
| 1 | this is another test for 110001 | 21/09/2022 9:20 | 2 |

My question is:

How can i reset ID column  of TableA without loosing the relation in TableB to make all ID's that i have Unique ?
Imagine that i have something like 1000 ID doubled in Table A, and usually for Each ID in TableB there are like 150 rows of different Tests, so i can't update them manually.
thanks in advance if you only take the time to read it.
i hope my question is quiet clear.

**EDIT**: Does exist a way maybe to delete all numbers from id column and reset them with an auto_increment or a cycle ? if i do it in TableA it will do the same on TableB automatically ? Because it will be perfect, the ID in those 2 table is only a relation to see what test is related to what NUMBER_ORDER so it doesn't matter if it change from 1 to 2 but the important thing is to make it unique.

Best regards.

As requested i'll try to make the tables more realistic as possible.

TableA as should it be:

| ID | ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 112563 |
| 2 | 116558 |
| 3 | 113365 |
| 4 | 102567 |
| 5 | 104758 |
| 6 | 105967 |

TableB as should it be :

| ID | teststep | key | min | max | value | res | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AFL | AFL_1_engine | 3500 | 3700 | 3567 | OK | 2018-12-19 16:52 |
| 1 | AFL | AFL_4_sitting | - | - | - | OK | 2018-12-19 16:53 |
| 2 | AFL | AFL_1_engine | 3500 | 3700 | 3780 | NOK | 2019-10-15 10:00 |
| 2 | AFL | AFL_1_engine | - | - | - | OK | 2019-10-15 10:02 |

exc... for others ID's

Answer (score 0):

When the correct values, that should be in TableA are returned by this query:

```sql
select
  row_number() over (order by value) as Id,
  value as NUMBER_ORDER
FROM (
   select 
      distinct  value
   from TableB
   cross apply string_split(test,' ')
   where value like '1%'
  ) x
```

You should be helped with this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/2lMsK3FB)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i can't delete TableA, because it is used in production, it will block the entire process, i don't have the permission to do it aswell :'(

Comment: Than you should get in touch with a co-worker who has permission to do that kind of stuff on a quiet time of the day (or night).

Comment: I think i should too, anyway, this part of the query:  cross apply string_split(test,' ')
   where value like '1%' what does it do ??

Comment: if  that solution is referring to the example "test" section it will not work cause the only existing things on the real table are ID's, the other columns are just an example of the format of the table.

Comment: [STRING_SPLIT](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/) will split the field `test` (i.e. `this is a test for 110000`) , with `value like `1%` I do a **simple** check to only return the numbers which in your example all start with a `1`.

Comment: ok, i imagine that was this. the real table doesn't have this line, i wrote it just to make understandable that the ID in TableB is referred to TableA, but the "test" is something more like " enginerpm" "rotor speed"  exc. there is no such number on that column.
the meaning is that ID 1 Have NUMBER_ORDER 110000 in TableA and the same ID in TableB is referred to it thanks to the relation from those 2 tables but it doesn't appear like on the example i made. in fact the problem is if i have the ID doubled i can't understand in TableB, wich test is referred to NUMBER_ORDER 110000 or 110001.

Comment: a [mre] will be needed to solve this correctly.